# Difference between tensorflow.keras and from tensorflow import keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I reinstalled tensorflow on a different machine. Previously, I used to import classes as:

```
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Loss
```

Now I do not see the module keras under tensorflow but I can use:

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

Is the latter the same as importing keras (many posts address that difference) or is from tensorflow import keras the same as tf.keras? Or maybe my installation failed somehow. I installed it via:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

According to https://www.tensorflow.org/install it should work.

Comment: Hi ! Both commands will show same behaviour (from Tensoflow import keras means Tensorflow will act like backend and help  run Tensorflow compatible Keras commands) and working perfectly. Attached [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/mohantym/9504e7bd67b702823ecc91fd35ea4e13/stack_72807531.ipynb) for reference. Please post more details for further assistance.

Comment: Thank you very much! It might also be due to a quirk in my IDE (I am using PyCharm). Despite the fact that the packages are underlined as if they were not recognized (e.g. from tensorflow.keras.losses import Loss, where .keras and Loss are underlined) running the script does not give an error. Any thoughts? Also, serendipitously, I found that from tensorflow.python.keras.losses import Loss will actually be acceptable. Is that yet another way to call the library?

Comment: Commands are Tensorflow.python are more private . won't recommend to use it in modelling.